# WPF Noob Seeking Guidance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

So, most of the time I live in ASP.NET MVC Land - however, right now I'm trying to make some analysis tools for our solution using WPF (aka, it would count lines of code, which files have tests, extracting meta data from attributes, etc). Everything is mostly going well (the reflection code I have works fine). What I'm having trouble with is the WPF ItemsControl. Compared to a tradition `<asp:Repeater />`, ItemsControl is completely boggling me.

My XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="repeaterRecentProjects">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="#094563" Margin="5" Padding="3">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image Source="/Content/Black-Internal-icon.png" Height="16" Width="16"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The idea is that the DataTemplate contains my template, as I understand it. Then, in code I can do something like this (EDIT: Full code behind of the page):

```
public partial class HomeScreen : Page
{
    protected bool _isProjectChosen = false;

    public HomeScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected ObservableCollection<string> someFiles = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        someFiles.Add("SomeFile.aspx");
        someFiles.Add("SomeFile2.aspx");
        someFiles.Add("SomeFile3.aspx");

        repeaterRecentProjects.ItemsSource = someFiles;
    }

    private void buttonSelectProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialogSelectProject = new OpenFileDialog();

        dialogSelectProject.DefaultExt = ".sln";
        dialogSelectProject.Filter = "Visual Studio Solution (.sln)|*.sln";

        if (dialogSelectProject.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            textBlockProjectName.Text = dialogSelectProject.FileName;
            _isProjectChosen = true;
            buttonAnalyzeProject.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        someFiles.Add("AnotherString.aspx");
    }

    private void buttonAnalyzeProject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click");
    }
}
```

However, whenever I run my application, **I don't see three items in my items control, only one item**. Why is this? Also, would my binding expression be correct? Since I'm not binding to a property of string, simply `{Binding}` should be acceptable right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Is being added to the the ItemsControl as an item instead of setting it as the `ItemsPanel`, this would be the right way:

```
    <ItemsControl>
        ...
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

(*This is redundant anyway, because the default panel is already a vertical StackPanel*)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ItemsSource on your items control

```
repeaterRecentProjects.ItemsSource = someFiles;
...snipped...
```

Comment: Now, I'm getting a different exception. `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.` I see now that DataContext was perhaps the wrong property to use when binding, but there should be no items in the list when this is run. Help?

Comment: @Tejs: you must be adding an item somewhere else in code. You can only use `Items` or `ItemsSource` - not both.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the full code behind of the xaml class. I'm not referencing repeaterRecentProjects's ItemsSource but once, and never the Items collection.

Comment: @Tejs, Maybe you should set the Items property instead of the ItemsSourceProperty, I'm not sure, I normally develop Silverlight and use the MVVM pattern so was just having an informed guess based on that knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem, but could use some guidance on why it was occuring. When I removed the following nodes from the XAML, it works correctly:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Why was it counting that template among the items collection? My understanding was that this was simply the container item it chose to add each data template to.